# Rcpp how to cast a DoubleVector to IntegerVector in a data frame

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a data frame `out` constructed. Suppose the first column in the data frame is constructed using `Rcpp::DoubleVector` and `REAL()`. I want to convert the entire column to a `Rcpp::IntegerVector` (much like what `as.integer()` does in base R).

I tried

`out[0] = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(out[0]);`

but R returns an error on the conversion.

Is there a way to make the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void toInt(DataFrame& x) {
  x[0] = as<IntegerVector>(x[0]);
}

/*** R
toInt(iris)
typeof(iris[[1]])
*/
```